# How to call a javascript function after loading the page in tinybox

Tags: javascript

I want to call a javascript function when the page is fully loaded in tiny box.

How to do this please help??

Comment: the tiny box you are talking about is an `iframe`??

Answer (score 1):

When you open a URL with TinyBox, it uses an iframe to load that page into the box that pops up. You can pass the `openjs` option a function, and that fires the function as a callback when the popup opens. However, I've noticed that this doesn't necessarily happen after the page within the iframe is fully loaded.

If the page you are loading into the iframe is on the same domain, you may be able to fire an event to the parent window from the iframe page. If you're using jQuery, it would be something like:

```
$(function() { 
  if (window.parent && window.parent.iframe_loaded) {
    window.parent.iframe_loaded();
  }
});
```

In the page that hosts the TinyBox popup, just define an `iframe_loaded` function in the global scope:

```
window.iframe_loaded = function() {
  alert('TinyBox popup page loaded');
};
```

If the page you are opening is not on the same domain, I don't know of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the openjs parameter inside TINY.box.show

```
 TINY.box.show({
```

..

openjs: function () { whatever you want },

..

})

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **openjs** like that way:

```
TINY.box.show({
url:'<?php echo FL_ADD_UPDATE_EMPLOYMENT_STATUS;?>',
width:480,
height:350,
opacity:TINY_OPACITY,
openjs:function(){scroll()} // like this.
});

function scroll() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```